# Converting parts of some string into another notation

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a big string of data and most of them are in the form Name = number^{number}_{-number}, some are in the form  Name = number \pm number. I what to convert the latter into the notation.

For a single line

```
singleLine = "c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910\\ pm 0.077 Dinc = -7.2\\ pm 5.3"
```

I used

```
StringReplace[singleLine, {("\\pm\ " ~~ y__ ~~ WhitespaceCharacter ~~ z_?LetterQ) -> ("^{+" ~~ y ~~ "}_{-" ~~ y ~~ "} " ~~ z), ("\\pm\ " ~~ y__ ~~ EndOfLine) -> ("^{+" ~~ y ~~ "}_{-" ~~ y ~~ "}")}]
```

and i got the desired format

```
"c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910^{+0.077}_{-0.077} Dinc = -7.2^{+5.3}_{-5.3}"
```

but when i try to use it for multiple lines

```
multipleLines = "c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910\\pm 0.077 Dinc = -7.2\\pm 5.3
c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910\\pm 0.077 Dinc = -7.2\\pm 5.3"
```

i get this

```
"c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910^{+0.077 Dinc = -7.2\\pm 5.3
c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910\\pm 0.077}_{-0.077 Dinc = -7.2\\pm 5.3
c200 = 9.5^{+1.2}_{-1.4} v200 = 279^{+200}_{-100} YD = 0.360^{+0.054}_{-0.079} df2 = 0.910\\pm 0.077} Dinc = -7.2^{+5.3}_{-5.3}"
```

I was wondering how can i properly select only the number after \pm to convert to the form that i want, and not what is after the number.

Comment: welcome to MMA SE! are you using underscores in a variable name? that's not permitted in mathematica; `single_line` will be interpreted as a pattern named `single` with head `line` (just as `x_Integer` is a pattern named `x` matching an `Integer`) which i don't think it what you want...! i'm surprised you didn't get an error when using it in `StringReplace`

Comment: I am not, i just used here to not repeat the long line twice, in the actual notebook i use string line with the full string provided as imput

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using Shortest[] as follows

```
StringReplace[
 multiple Lines, 
 "\\pm " ~~ Shortest[y__] ~~ WhitespaceCharacter -> 
  "^{+" ~~ y ~~ "}_{-" ~~ y ~~ "} "]
```

which works for both the single and multiple lines cases. In my specific case, the location of WhitespaceCharacter was key, even at the end of a line or string to be able to match the patter and replace it.